# Prove that in $\Bbb R$, $Int ([0,1]) = (0,1) $

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

Basically I need to show $Int([0,1]) = (0,1)$ meaning that I need to show that:

$(0,1) =  \bigcup_{a \in A}a$ 
Where for all $a \in A, a = (b,c)$ where $b,c$ real numbers such that $0 <b <c <1$

Thoughts:

Let $x \in (0,1)$ then $0 <b<x <c <1$ for some $b$, $c$ real numbers, then $x \in (b,c)$ for some $b$, $c$ real numbers and so $x \in a$ for some $a \in A$ and so $x \in \bigcup_{a \in A}a$.

Let $x \in \bigcup_{a \in A}a$, then $x \in a$ for some $a \in A$, then $0 <b <x <c <1$ for some $b$, $c$ real numbers then $0 <x <1$ then $x \in (0,1) \blacksquare $

I think it's right but I still feel a tiny bit fishy about it.

Thanks.

Comment: You should be more explicit about your reasoning. What are $b$ and $c$ in the first part, for example?

Comment: @IbrahimTencer Yes, I'll edit the text to mention that they are reals.

Comment: What I meant was $b=0$ and $c = 1$. The way you have it written above makes it sound tautological - it's best to explain *why* it's true.

Answer (score 0):

If i interprete what you have written :

$(0,1)$  (the set $A$ is the set of  connected neighborhoods of elements in $(0,1)$ included in $(0,1)$) is union of elements of $A$.

Basically what you are showing is that $(0,1)$ is a neighborhood of each of its point. This only show that $(0,1)$ is open and  to demonstrate this, it is much easier to show that around each point of $(0,1)$ you have a little ball  included in  $(0,1)$.

Then you know that $(0,1)$ is a open set included in $[0,1]$. But the interior of $[0,1]$ is the biggest open set included in $[0,1]$ (and I do not think you mentionned this in your proof). But it is quite easy, if we are looking for a bigger set than $(0,1)$ included in $[0,1]$ it leaves you with four choices :

$$(0,1)\text{, } [0,1)\text{, }(0,1] \text{ or } [0,1] $$

The last three cannot be open (why ?) so that to be open and between $(0,1)$ and $[0,1]$ you can't but be $(0,1)$. This show that the biggest open set included in $[0,1]$ is $(0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks. I still haven't covered balls and connectedness so I don't know how to utilise them just yet. But is my basic proof correct for the moment?

Comment: Well, you express $(0,1)$ as a union of open sets and deduce it is open, so your proof is correct. What I wanted to say is just that you have an easier way (in my opinion it is quicker but ...) to do it and regarding the question you don't answer it completely (but maybe you just wanted a hand on the open set thing)...